# Using clusters reverses the order of rank=same

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a digraph which I've set to "rankdir=LR;" so that "rank=same" will be top-to-bottom.

I decided to add a few clusters to this graph, but as a result "rank=same" has now become bottom-to-top.

A minimal example shows the problem:

```
digraph graph {
graph [
    rankdir=LR;
    nodesep = "0.5 equally",
    newrank = true;
];

/* Guide Nodes */
rank1 [style=dotted];
rank2 [style=dotted];
rank1 -> rank2 [style=dotted];

/* Node Clusters */
subgraph cluster1 {
A;
B;
C;
}

/* Node Hierarchy */
A -> Z;
B -> Z;
C -> Z;

/* Node Rank */
{   rank=same;
rank1 -> A -> B -> C [style=dotted];
}

} /* Closes the digraph */
```

The result that I want is to have from top to bottom: rank1, A, B, C.

The result that I get is from top to bottom: C, B, A, rank1 --- as seen in the picture below.

[image]

How can I get the correct order back?

- Option 1: Just don't use clusters.
- Option 2: Rewrite the "rank=same" line to fit the bottom-to-top direction.

Given the size of my graph, option 2 is simply too much work for too little gain. Is there another option?

EDIT: The answer that marapet gave, does most of what I wanted. However, that solution doesn't work with the following minimal problem:

```
digraph g {
graph [
    rankdir=LR;
    nodesep = "0.5 equally",
    newrank = true;
];

/* Node Clusters */
subgraph cluster1 {
    subgraph cluster2 {
    A;
    B;
    C;
    }
P;
    subgraph cluster4 {
    D;
    E;
    F;
    }
Z;
}

/* Guide Nodes */
rank1 [style=dotted];
rank2 [style=dotted];

/* Guide Nodes Hierarchy */
rank1 -> rank2 [style=dotted];

/* Node Hierarchy */
A -> Z;
B -> Z;
C -> Z;
P -> Z;
D -> Z;
E -> Z;
F -> Z;

/* Rank Constraints */
rank1 -> A -> B -> C -> P -> D -> E -> F [style=dotted, constraint=false];

} /* Closes the digraph */
```

This results in the following picture:

[image]

I can only conclude that the issue I'm having is the result of mixing clusters and non-clusters in the same-rank-edges.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `rank=same`, you may use `constraint=false` for the same-ranke-edges:

```
/* Node Rank */
rank1 -> A -> B -> C [style=dotted, constraint=false];
```

The order of appearance of the nodes (guide nodes and node clusters) should also be changed:

```
digraph g {
graph [
    rankdir=LR;
    nodesep = "0.5 equally",
    newrank = true;
];

/* Node Clusters */
subgraph cluster1 {
A;
B;
C;
}

/* Guide Nodes */
rank1 [style=dotted];
rank2 [style=dotted];
rank1 -> rank2 [style=dotted];

/* Node Hierarchy */
A -> Z;
B -> Z;
C -> Z;

/* Node Rank */
rank1 -> A -> B -> C [style=dotted, constraint=false];
}
```

In general, for LR layouts, it helps to lay out the graph top-down and imagine it rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution did most of what I wanted, but then broke down. I've edited my question to demonstrate how it broke down. I'll accept your answer when I know that problem cannot be solved.

Comment: I thought the approach was to first provide node information, then edge information and then rank constraints? (According to which I still made the mistake you pointed out.)

Comment: How about packing your P node into a cluster and hide the cluster bounding rectangle with `color=white` ?

Answer (score 1):

Small extension to edit in the question.
In the edit the lone node 'p' is used, packing it in a subgraph gives a better result, especially when setting the color to white: like:

```
subgraph cluster3 {
P;
graph[color=white];
}
```

Only strange thing I get in my output is that there are 2 dotted lines between 'C' and 'P'/
Playing around with the 'dir=back' gave a solution.
Complete code:

```
digraph g {
graph [
    rankdir=LR;
    nodesep = "0.5 equally",
    newrank = true;
];

/* Node Clusters */
subgraph cluster1 {
    subgraph cluster2 {
    A;
    B;
    C;
    }
    subgraph cluster3 {
    P;
    graph[color=white];
    }
    subgraph cluster4 {
    D;
    E;
    F;
    }
    Z;
}

/* Guide Nodes */
rank1 [style=dotted];
rank2 [style=dotted];

/* Guide Nodes Hierarchy */
rank1 -> rank2 [style=dotted];

/* Node Hierarchy */
A -> Z;
B -> Z;
C -> Z;
P -> Z;
D -> Z;
E -> Z;
F -> Z;

/* Rank Constraints */
rank1 -> A -> B -> C [style=dotted, constraint=false];
D -> E -> F [style=dotted, constraint=false];
P -> C [dir=back, style=dotted, constraint=false];
P -> D [style=dotted, constraint=false];

} /* Closes the digraph */
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I gave up when I encountered the 2 dotted lines problem, because I needed a break by then. It's exhausting to hack the algorithm instead of simply telling it what to do.